# What is a word or phrase that describes someone changes themselves in order to fit a role?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Does anyone have a clue or an idiomatic phrase for this:

> When someone changes themselves in order to **fit a role**

Ex: When someone gets a new job, they learn new abilities to suit that role.
Ex2: When someone becomes what their significant other needs rather than staying the same.

Comment: Are you looking for a positive word (someone can adjust well to change) or a negative one (someone isn't authentic and just follows others)?

Comment: 'Make some adjustments' is what I'd use, but it's far too much of a hypernym to offer as an answer.

Comment: You mean something other than learning specific skills needed for the job?

Answer (score 2):

We may say that the person **grows into** the role.

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grow-into)
> *Grow into something*:
> if you grow into a situation or activity, you gradually start knowing what to do because you have more experience
> *She needs time to grow into her new role.*

A typical example is this title for an article on developing leadership skills:

> [Aha!](https://www.aha.io/blog/grow-into-a-leadership-role)
> “6 Questions to Ask If You Want to Grow Into a Leadership Role”

Answer (score 1):

How about *to adapt*? It's not an idiomatic phrase, but it works pretty well.

Per [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/adapt),

> to change your ideas or behavior to make them suitable for a new situation

The examples it offers are pretty similar to what you described,

> 1. The good thing about children is that they adapt very easily to new environments.
> 2. It took me a while to adapt to the new job.

Answer (score 0):

***[Conform](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conform)*** may express the idea you are suggesting:

> to behave according to a group’s usual standards and expectations, or to operate according to a rule:
>
> - The contract requires that managers conform to high standards of personal conduct.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Conform to new rules, conform to someone’s expectations or needs, etc.

Comment: This actually makes sense. I was under the impression that conform was only for situations, rather than peoples expectations as well. Good word. Thanks

Comment: @Elainor If an answer helps you out, you can show your appreciation by voting them up. This way, proper answers will stand out, *and* you reward people for their time and aid. Welcome to ELU!

Answer (score 0):

You can say that you ***mould yourself*** according to the new circumstances of your job or according to the needs of another person.

> To mould someone or something means to change or influence them over a period of time so that they develop in a particular way.
>
> - Too often we try to ***mould*** our children into something they do not wish to be. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mould))

Answer (score 0):

To reinvent oneself is a phrase sometimes used.

> She reinvented herself as a singer.

> He reinvented himself as an ideal husband.

It refers to fairly significant change in a way those who knew the person before might find surprising.